Dmesg logs littered with Upowered Segfaults
My dmesg logs, as the title states, are absolutely littered with these types of messages:
[422198.529132] gsd-power[912439]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f7e6a314620 sp 00007ffdc87279a0 error 4 in libupower-glib.so.3.1.0[7f7e6a312000+f000] likely on CPU 8 (core 16, socket 0)
[422198.529139] Code: 8b 3c 24 ba 13 00 00 00 89 c6 e8 6b e4 ff ff 85 c0 75 b6 48 8b 04 24 48 8d 15 6c ce 00 00 be 10 00 00 00 48 8d 3d 2a cd 00 00 <48> 8b 48 08 31 c0 e8 95 eb ff ff eb 92 e8 5e e6 ff ff 66 66 2e 0f
[422248.768839] gsd-power[912640]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f328935e620 sp 00007ffc1e0246f0 error 4 in libupower-glib.so.3.1.0[7f328935c000+f000] likely on CPU 18 (core 34, socket 0)
[422248.768850] Code: 8b 3c 24 ba 13 00 00 00 89 c6 e8 6b e4 ff ff 85 c0 75 b6 48 8b 04 24 48 8d 15 6c ce 00 00 be 10 00 00 00 48 8d 3d 2a cd 00 00 <48> 8b 48 08 31 c0 e8 95 eb ff ff eb 92 e8 5e e6 ff ff 66 66 2e 0f
[422299.025374] gsd-power[912817]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f05e74dc620 sp 00007fff597973c0 error 4 in libupower-glib.so.3.1.0[7f05e74da000+f000] likely on CPU 12 (core 24, socket 0)
[422299.025381] Code: 8b 3c 24 ba 13 00 00 00 89 c6 e8 6b e4 ff ff 85 c0 75 b6 48 8b 04 24 48 8d 15 6c ce 00 00 be 10 00 00 00 48 8d 3d 2a cd 00 00 <48> 8b 48 08 31 c0 e8 95 eb ff ff eb 92 e8 5e e6 ff ff 66 66 2e 0f

Furthermore, and I believe this is related, I am unable to open the gnome-control-center. It's pretty annoying.
$ gnome-control-center

(gnome-control-center:914120): libupower-glib-WARNING **: 18:05:41.682: Couldn't connect to proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.UPower: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.UPower': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)

It just kind of hangs for a bit and then dies with no useful indication of why it is dying other than not being able to interact with upowerd. Oh, and then it core dumps...
(gnome-control-center:915922): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:15:44.693: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gnome-control-center:915922): libupower-glib-CRITICAL **: 18:15:44.766: up_client_get_devices_full: assertion 'UP_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I didn't have these issues when running Ubuntu on this box but I don't particularly care for Ubuntu, I find Debian to be a cleaner and less bloated at a slight expense of lack of compatibility. I am not certain if that is the case here, or if it's something else.
I don't know how to fix this, apparently. Tried reinstalling upowered and using non-free vs free firmware with no difference. I updated my bios. No results. I tried lightdm instead of gdm. Switching to gnome-session-fallback works of course, but that feels too much like 2013 to me. I don't want to deal with reflashing again. Especially not knowing if it will make a difference. Would rather solve the problem so I know what's going on. Also I do not know if those dmesg logs are anything to be concerned about?
Can anyone assist me in debugging and resolving this issue? Would be very appreciated.

The first hit on searching for gsd-power brings up possible solutions. Always do some basic research first before asking.

I don't see anything relevant. This is a desktop system btw.

I FINALLY fixed this...
Turns out I guess I for some reason had a custom init script to start upower, which I don't remember if I configured so I should probably nuke this box ... in any case , turns out the command line option -z, which is not a valid option to the upower binary was being passed by the init script. I removed that and now it's fine.
So, check to make sure you don't have duplicate services trying to start the same binary if you cannot figure out why a service will not start a binary.
It's possible I configured this when I was hardening this system for whatever reason, I think I vaguley remember but idk why I did that, if I did that.
Anyway. It works. Finally.
